# Omitting one or multiple values in javascript using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a complex structure and I want to omit some properties from this structure for final value

```
let ListofWorlds = {
    listOfCountries: [{
        add: [{
            id: 1,
            updated: {
                areacode: 123,
                city: {
                    city: {'Austrailia'},
                    houses: {1000}
                }
            }
        }], remove: []
    }]
}
```

I want to omit city property from this structure and need this

```
let ListofWorlds = {
    listOfCountries: [{
        add: [{
            id: 1,
            updated: {
                areacode: 123
            }
        }], remove: []
    }]
}
```

This is what I have tried

```
let newListOfWorls = _.map(ListofWorlds, function (worlds) {
    return _.omit(worlds, ['city']); })
```

Appreciate the help and knowledge

Comment: Please share your code so far. What did you try, what failed?

Comment: @elclanrs i tried the _.omit function but it returns me back the same object

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried.

```
let ListofWorlds = {
listOfCountries: [{
    add: [{
        id: 1,
        updated: {
            areacode: 123,
            city: {
                city: 'Austrailia',
                houses: 1000
            }
        }
    }], remove: []
}]}

const newList = ListofWorlds.listOfCountries.map(arr=>{ 
arr.add.forEach((item,index)=>{
    arr.add[index] = _.omit(item,'updated.city')
  })
  return arr
})
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but hey it works, and why your code doesn't work probably you mapped an Object `ListofWorlds` and you need to be specific which field you want to be omitted